# CSS animation doesn't work in Safari :/

Tags: css, animation, safari

I displayed a CSS animation on my website and it doesn't work in Safari.
Any idea of what I missed?

```
.arrow {
    background-image: url(../img/arrow.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    -webkit-animation: arrow 3.5s infinite;
    animation: arrow 3.5s infinite;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}


/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
@-webkit-keyframes arrow {
    0%   {top: 0;}
    100% {top: 50px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes arrow {
    0%   {top: 0;}
    100% {top: 50px;}
}
```

Comment: What version of Safari?

Comment: refer to http://www.caniuse.com for animation compatibility. Check your version first

Comment: Hi and thank you all for your answers.@AndrewStaker I am using the 8.0.7 version of Safari

Comment: @RachelGallen thanks for the link ! It says that the version of Safari I use supports it so I guess something is wrong with my code ?

Comment: @user4821030 please post your html then

Comment: @user4821030  http://jsfiddle.net/8pam49pr/ this fiddle works in safari for windows

Comment: @RachelGallen THANK YOU SO MUCH !!

Comment: @user4821030 hover beside answer and click the tick!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be your image path. Put in the full image path and you will notice that your code works. See the fiddle (jsfiddle.net/8pam49pr). It works in Safari - I have tested it - no adjustment, except that i specified a full file path.